# How to setup fable-elmish-react native app?

Tags: android, react-native, f#, fable-f#, elmish

I'm able to setup Elmish-React by following https://github.com/fable-elmish/react

```
dotnet new -i "Fable.Template.Elmish.React::*"
dotnet new fable-elmish-react -n MyProject
```

but I can't figure out what I need to do to get the equivalent native app. I want to be able to get the simple counter example working from https://fable-elmish.github.io/react/native.html.

I've tried creating a react-native app with

```
$ npm install -g react-native-cli
$ react-native init AwesomeProject
```

This is great, but it gives me a Javascript project and I don't understand how to plugin or adjust it to make an F# project with Fable.

Comment: I suspect that the workflow is (at least partially) described here : https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

Comment: Have you had a look at the nightwatch demo using the SAFE stack: https://github.com/SAFE-Stack/SAFE-Nightwatch ?

Comment: @spender yes, that is what I followed in the second part. The issue I have is finding out how to hook the F# in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Native story has been somewhat neglected since I'm not using it myself, but [this example](https://github.com/elmish/sample-rn-counter) has been updated a few month ago to fairly recent tooling and it should be a good base to start from. Most of it is what you'd get from `react-native init`, so just clone and start playing with it.